# How to combine an openstreetmap with points in R

Tags: r, graphics, ggplot2, ggmap

I'm just starting off learning R and I'm attempting to create a map that shows the number of students in each town in Connecticut. I've got a .csv of location and enrollment info that looks like this:

```
name       lon      lat resStudent
1   ANDOVER          -72.37472 41.73278        657
2   ANSONIA          -73.07900 41.34621       2999
3   ASHFORD          -72.12162 41.87307        736
4   AVON             -72.83052 41.80962       3563
5   BARKHAMSTED      -72.97222 41.92917        680
6   BEACON FALLS     -73.06176 41.44265       1039
7   BERLIN           -72.78064 41.61460       3165
8   BETHANY          -72.99250 41.42556       1028
9   BETHEL           -73.41396 41.37123       3034
10  BETHLEHEM        -73.20861 41.63917        490
11  BLOOMFIELD       -72.73336 41.83945       2484
```

I've been able to generate the map that I'd like to overlay this information on using the following code:

```
tempMap <- get_openstreetmap(bbox = c(left = -73.8, bottom = 40.9, right = -71.7, top = 42.1), scale = 829486, color = "bw")
ggmap(tempMap)
```

I'm running in to a problem combining the two. Here is the code I'm using:

```
enrollData<-read.csv("enrollData.csv")   
enrollMap <- tempMap + geom_point(data = enrollData,aes(x = lon, y = lat, size = resStudent)
```

After this runs, I get an error message that reads:

```
Error in Ops.raster(tempMap, geom_point(data = enrollData, aes(x = lon,  : 
  Operator not meaningful for raster objects
```

Any ideas for how to fix this?

Comment: did you try: `ggmap(tempMap) + geom_point(data = enrollData,aes(x = lon, y = lat, size = resStudent)`?

Comment: cool! got a screenshot?

Comment: Here's a screenshot using a cloudmap instead of an openstreetmap: http://twitpic.com/caglh1

Answer (score 4):

You need to call `ggmap` first create the base layer. The following should work:

```
ggmap(tempMap) + geom_point(data = enrollData,aes(x = lon, y = lat, size = resStudent)
```